# How i can simulate code typing in textarea in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a Textarea for input programming code. Does anyone know how to make a space after typing curly braces {} and press enter key?

```
{
    name: 'John'
}
```

but not

```
{
name:'John'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're actually asking for is the ability to run a linter/prettifier against a given text string. There would be all kinds of issues here. First and foremost, you have to make sure it's valid json before you tried to lint/prettify it.

However, if you can guarantee that the user is going to paste in *valid* json, you could do something like this:

Here's an example JSON string. Paste it into the left textarea and it will update the right area to a prettified format. (Event is triggered on textarea change)

```
{"id":1,"name":"Leanne Graham","username":"Bret","email":"Sincere@april.biz","address":{"street":"Kulas Light","suite":"Apt. 556","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"92998-3874","geo":{"lat":"-37.3159","lng":"81.1496"}},"phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442","website":"hildegard.org","company":{"name":"Romaguera-Crona","catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net","bs":"harness real-time e-markets"}}
```

```js
document.getElementById('txt').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const text = e.target.value;
  try {
    const obj = JSON.parse(text);
    const pretty = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('prettyText').value = pretty;
  } catch (ex) {
    console.warn('Invalid JSON');
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <h5>Original</h5>
    <textarea type="text" rows="10" id="txt"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h5>Pretty</h5>
    <textarea type="text" rows="10" id="prettyText"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may also have some look taking at this: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/library/

Looks like TSLint offers a way to programmatically run a linter against something. You might be able to find a way to make that work by posting your text to a node endpoint or something. Take a look at npm too. Lots of linter/json prettifiers on there.

Comment: Hey!! Thanks a million for answer) I found the library CodeMirror - with this lib you can make your text area be like IDE (with text highlight, indentation and etc).